# Delete records from a database or simply hide them during Reads?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm wondering if someone can provide various rationales/solutions for knowing when to delete records from a database vs. simplying hiding them during read operations via a field value, e.g., `is_hidden=1`.

My application is a social network/e-commerce web application. I tend to favor the `is_hidden` strategy but as one's site grows I can see this leading to a really badly performing site.

Here's my list. What items on the list am I missing? Is the list's prioritization good?

`Delete`:

1. rationale: Reduce table size/improve database performance
2. rationale: Useful if data is trivial to create
3. solution: SQL `DELETE`

`is_hidden`:

1. rationale: allow users/DBA to restore data/useful for sensitive & hard to `CREATE` data
2. rationale: can `DELETE` it later if necessary
3. solution: SQL `SELECT ... WHERE is_hidden!=1`

Thoughts?

Comment: you have given your rationales and it's up to you to decide. `:D` select the best which perfectly fit on your situation..

Comment: This might be more suited to the DBA stack exchange. However, we generally go for the option of logical delete (hidden/deleted field) and make it a dev task to regularly backup and clear out that "deleted" data. This way you keep the simplicity & ability of audit trails of just logically deleting things, but keep that data under control by removing it every so often.

Comment: It really depends on your own situation.  Sometimes you can delete and other times you soft delete data.

Comment: You can also consider moving old data to archive/ audit table. This allows data restore, but yet original table size is reduced to maintain performance.

Comment: Depends on what you need - remember that you would also need to handle the case where an entity holds a reference to another entity which used to exist but has since been deleted (and whether you CASCADE etc in the db). At least with the 'hidden' method you can still safely delete/undelete the entity, but it adds a little complexity to fetching 'active' entities. It also depends on how your application will display data and the architecture of the DB. I suppose the key questions are: Is there any reason you need to keep old deleted data? Is there any reason you need to retain old deleted date?

Comment: @NaN thanks I hadn't thought of an `audit` table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major reason you might want to do a soft-delete is where an audit trail requires it.  For example we might have an invoice table along with an voided column and we might normally just omit voided invoices.  This preserves an audit trail so we know what invoices were entered and which ones were voided.

There are many fields (particularly in finance) where soft deletes are preferred for this reason.  Typically the number of deletes are small compared to the data set, and you don't want to really delete because actually doing so might allow someone to cover for theft of money or real-world goods.  The "deleted" data can then be shown for those queries which require it.

A good non-db example would be as follows:  "When writing in your general journal or general ledger, write with a pen and if you make an error that you spot right away, cross it out with a single line so that the original data is still legible, and write correct values underneath.  If you find out later, either write in an adjustment entry or write in a reversal and a new one."  In that case, your principle reason is to see what was changed when so that you can audit those changes if there is ever a question.

The people typically needing to see such information are likely to be financial or other auditors.

Answer (score 4):

You've already said everthing in your question:

**DELETE** will entirely delete the entry and

**is_hidden=1** will hide it.

So: If there's the possibility that you will need the data in the future you should use the hiding method. If you are sure that the data will never ever be used again: Use delete.

**Concerning performance:**

You can use two tables:

- 1 for visible items
- 1 for the hidden ones

Or even three tables:

- 1 for visible
- 1 for hidden
- 1 as an archive, where you move all the hidden data that's older than 3 years or something

Or:

- 1 for visible and hidden ones (using the is_hidden flag)
- 1 as an archive for old entries

It's all up to you. But if you look at facebook or google: They will never ever delete anything! Data == Money == Power ;)

Answer (score 1):

As far as performance and ease of development, it may be possible on your platform to have filtered indexes, indexed views etc which would mean that keeping the soft-deleted data around  has little impact on your system.

Comment: i'm using mysql and can develop the queries however I chose. Can you explain a little more about filtered indexes and indexed views?

Comment: @timpeterson MySQL does not have an equivalent of either of those features.  Postgres does, however http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_index